# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat: Wednesday October 26th, 18:00 UTC / 2pm Eastern

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the [moderator elections](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election/1), we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Wednesday the 26th at 6pm UTC / 2pm EDT.**

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=10&day=26&year=2011&hour=18&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1646/sharepoint-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

---

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase. I'm operating on the assumption that there won't be a primary phase.  This means that I am looking at the 25th-27th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=sharepoint.stackexchange.com).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: I think this is the correct registration link: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1646/sharepoint-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule